# Print area not saved when an excel file is opened through powershell script

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an excel file that has a print area set. I need to open this file through a powershell script

```
$path = [io.path]::combine($env:APPDATA, "Dubhe\\Letteratura.xlsx");
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application;
$excel.visible = $true;
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.open($path);
```

The problem is that when I execute the script, the excel file opens but when I try to print it the print area is no longer set. I tried also with other files, but the result is the same. I used Excel 2016